# How can i use more different forms in the same Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

In my project, i have a template where i'm trying to put two forms for different use cases. I've never come across this problem before, so i don't really know where to go from here to use two forms in the same page.

At first i thought of creating another view to handle each form, but i think that this solution would create problems with the rendering of my templates, other than not being sustainable if i should have this problem again with another template.

After making some research, i found a solution but it works for class based views, but i'd like to avoid that since my view is already a function based view, and i would have to make a lot of changes in my code.

Would it be possible to solve this problem with a function based view? Every advice is appreciated

**First field**

```
class FirstForm(forms.ModelForm):

    firstfield = forms.CharField() 
    secondfield = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("firstfield", "secondfield")
    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(FirstForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send**
```

**Second Form**

```
class SecondForm(forms.ModelForm):

    firstfield = forms.FloatField() 
    secondfield = forms.Floatfield()
    thirdfield = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModelTwo
        fields = ("firstfield", "secondfield", "thirdfield")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        send = super(SecondForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            send.save()
        return send
```

**Template**

```
  <h3> First Form </h3>
  <form method="post" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% include 'main/includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: red;">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>

  <h3> Second Form </h3>
  <form method="post" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% include 'main/includes/bs4_form.html' with form=form %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: red;">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
```

EDIT: my view:

```
def myview(request):

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = FirstForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            send = form.save()
            send.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Success")

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = FirstForm()

    return render(request,
                  "main/mytemplate.html",
                  context={"form":form})
```

Comment: Quite apart from anything else, please note that your two `save` methods replicate exactly what the superclass save method does; they are pointless, you should remove them.

Comment: Can you include your current view code?

Comment: I'm removing them @DanielRoseman, thanks! I also added the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a bit general because you haven't included your view function. You can add each of these forms to your view's context. Something like this:

#### views.py

```py
...
from .forms import FirstForm, SecondForm
...

def some_view(request):

    context = {
        'first_form': FirstForm(request.POST or None),
        'second_form': SecondForm(request.POST or None)
    }
    return render(request, "app/some_template.html", context)
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry, i forgot to add the view. I just added it right now

Comment: One thing i do not understand, how do i specify which form is which in the template?

Comment: Simply reference `first_form` or `second_form` instead of `form`.